# insert facebook element if user can connect to facebook

Tags: jquery, javascript

I want to use javascript to check whether my user browser can connect to facebook. If it's ok, the webpage will display a facebook element of a fan page. The original code of facebook for inserting a facebook fanpage element is:

```
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1"></script>
            <fb:like href="facebook.com/xxxxx" show_faces="true" width="380px" height="1px" font=""></fb:like>
```

And I use this code for checking whether an user can connect to facebook to display the fanpage element:

```
$(function()
                {

                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'http://graph.facebook.com',
                        dataType: 'jsonp',
                        success: function() {
                            $.getScript('http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1', function()
                                    {
                                        $('#divfb_embed').append('<fb:like href="facebook.com/phamimports" show_faces="true" width="380px" height="1px" font=""></fb:like>');
                                    }); 
                        },
                        error : function(data)
                        {
                            alert("error");
                        }
                    });

                });
```

However, when the code run into success function, the fanpage element does not display normally. I think that there are some special codes in the facebook javascript for displayin a fanpage element. 
Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my take on things... I could be wrong. The facebook sdk initializes when the document ready event fires and parses the page looking for `<fb:blah>` tags to render them as html.

Because you are inserting the facebook javascript files after the document ready event fires, the facebook initialization never fires and your like button isn't going to appear.

Either that or the success function that appends the `<fb:like>` tag is happening after the loaded script is executed.

Either way I would suggest that you just wrap the `<fb:like>` in a `<div>` that is hidden and then once you know a user can connect to facebook, you can then show the hidden `<div>`.

Comment: oh, thanks a lot for a tricky solution. However, this is a good solution to this time. +1 for a smart solution